# Positioning images on a page (HTML)

Tags: html, css

These images are using a CSS code for hovering effects, everything works good except i have no idea how to re arrange their position on the page.

Right now they are horizontally on top of each other, how can i make them side by side?:

```css
body {
      color:#000000;
      background-color:#000000;
      background-image:url('Background Image');
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
    a  { color:#0000FF; }
    a:visited { color:#800080; }
    a:hover { color:#008000; }
    a:active { color:#FF0000; }
    #cf {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com/page1">
<div id="cf">
<img class="bottom" src="images/img_a_1.jpg" />
<img class="top" src="images/img_a_2.jpg" />
</div></a>

<a href="http://example.com/page2">
<div id="cf">
<img class="bottom" src="images/img_b_1.jpg" />
<img class="top" src="images/img_b_2.jpg" />
</div></a>

<a href="http://example.com/page3">
<div id="cf">
<img class="bottom" src="images/img_c_1.jpg" />
<img class="top" src="images/img_c_2.jpg" />
</div></a>
```

Comment: use position:relative, float: left or display:inline-block on #cf img

Comment: #cf should not be repeated, since IDs are supposed to be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As arhak has previously commented, we do not use an id more than once on a page, they must be unique. Here are the following changes:

- > Changed each `#cf` to class `.cf`.
- > Added `display:table-cell` to each `.cf` so that they are side-by-side.
- Changed each `.cf` dimensions to something manageable 50 x 50px.
- Replaced non-functioning `<img>` `src` to working values*.
- Decreased the size of each `.cf` to 50 x 50px*.

All of these changes are optional with the exception of the first and second changes.

*I know that your relative urls work for you, but an example that doesn't work here will make things harder to demonstrate. In the future if you have images, use those or images of equivalent size in your examples. If we don't know that 50 x 50px is insufficient for your requirements, that will slowdown the process in finding a resolution.

#### SNIPPET

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-image: url('Background Image');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
a {
  color: #0000FF;
}
a:visited {
  color: #800080;
}
a:hover {
  color: #008000;
}
a:active {
  color: #FF0000;
}
.cf {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:table-cell;
}
.cf img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.cf img.top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="http://example.com/page1">
    <div class="cf">
      <img class="bottom" src='http://placehold.it/50x50/00f/fff?text=1'>
      <img class="top" src='http://placehold.it/50x50/cf0/000?text=2'>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="http://example.com/page2">
    <div class="cf">
      <img class="bottom" src='http://placehold.it/50x50/0e0/110?text=3'>
      <img class="top" src='http://placehold.it/50x50/0bb/011?text=4'>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="http://example.com/page3">
    <div class="cf">
      <img class="bottom" src='http://placehold.it/50x50/fff/000?text=5'>
      <img class='top' src='http://placehold.it/50x50/f00/fff?text=6'>
    </div>
  </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 body {
      color:#000000;
      background-color:#000000;
      background-image:url('Background Image');
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
    a  { color:#0000FF; }
    a:visited { color:#800080; }
    a:hover { color:#008000; }
    a:active { color:#FF0000; }
    

#cf img {
  text-align: center;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<a href="http://example.com/page1">
<div class="col-xs-12 form-group" id="cf">
<img class="bottom col-xs-6" src="images/img_a_1.jpg" />
<img class="top col-xs-6" src="images/img_a_2.jpg" />
</div></a>

<a href="http://example.com/page2">
<div class="col-xs-12 form-group" id="cf">
<img class="bottom col-xs-6" src="images/img_b_1.jpg" />
<img class="top col-xs-6" src="images/img_b_2.jpg" />
</div></a>

<a href="http://example.com/page3">
<div class="col-xs-12 form-group" id="cf">
<img class="bottom col-xs-6" src="images/img_c_1.jpg" />
<img class="top col-xs-6" src="images/img_c_2.jpg" />
</div></a>
  </body>
```